# Is it possible that humans could ever evolve to handle the Sun's radiation without anything to protect us?

Tags: evolution, science-in-society, sunlight

I was thinking about how humans have evolved from apes to what we are now, while apes still remain a species that isn't extinct. Is it possible that the human race will evolve into a species that could possibly be able to handle the sun's radiation without an atmosphere to protect us, while humans like us remain an active species (even though by that time, probably millions of years we would've migrated to another planet because of the human species dying off otherwise on earth)?

Comment: We can't breath without an atmosphere,

Comment: As I said on James K's answer - Humans will make radiation-proof clothing, move to Mars, or build a new magnetosphere instead of evolving. With  medication, surgeries, and life support preventing those "unfit" to survive radiation from dying, survival of the fittest won't allow evolution to adapt people naturally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of things here. First you say "humans have evolved from apes to what we are now, while apes still remain a species". This isn't quite true.  Instead, there was about 7 million years ago an animal living in Africa that was ancestral to Chimps, Bonobo and Humans. This species doesn't exist any more. Speaking casually, it would be described as an "ape", in the sense it is a non-human, tailless primate. But the word "ape" doesn't describe a branch of the tree of life, as it is defined by exclusion. So it is not correct to say that apes are a species, nor that humans evolved from an ape that is still around.

Ok, that out the way. "Can humans evolve to a form that can handle solar radiation without a protective atmosphere?" -- Yes, but solar radiation is the last of your problems if you don't have an atmosphere.

The easiest way to protect against the sun is to develop a thick coat of hair. Solar radiation is not so very harmful and some hair would block most of the damaging UV. If there was selection pressure for a group of humans to to evolve along these lines there would be nothing to stop them. By selection pressure I mean that those who had thinner hair were more likely to die without reproducing than those with thicker hair. Cosmic rays are higher energy and would be a problem leading to higher cancer rates. The natural solution to this would be to mature younger, and so reproduce at a younger age. So my post-humans are precocious furries...

And if another group of humans were not subject to the same selection pressure they would evolve differently. Yet, over evolutionary time they would still evolve.

However, not having an atmosphere is a rather extreme situation. You would die of suffocation long before you had to worry about solar radiation. You can't rush evolution. You can't just dump some humans in a high radiation environment and expect them to evolve rapidly. It must happen gradually over hundreds of thousands of years.

Comment: If given hundreds of thousands of years, humans will make radiation-proof clothing, move to Mars, or build a new magnetosphere; in a world where medication, surgeries, and life support prevent those "unfit" to survive from dying, survival of the fittest won't allow evolution to deal with radiation. Not your fault because you answered the question well but it is worth noting --

Answer (score 2):

This question should probably be rephrased for greater scientific accuracy, but the core is good. Perhaps the question could be rephrased as:

> "Could humans survive without the radiation protections we enjoy here on
>   earth?"

There are many kinds of radiation. (Forgive me if this sounds simplistic at the beginning, but I'm gearing my explanation towards the level scientific knowledge implied by the question) The most well-known type of solar radiation which is blocked by the atmosphere is ultraviolet light. Specifically it's blocked by a very thin layer of mono-molecular oxygen in the upper atmosphere (Ozone). A sheet of cloth provides just as much protection as the Ozone layer, so it's hard to imagine a time or place where we could breathe and lack this protection. (Imagine a plastic dome over a crater on the surface of Mars. The dome is necessary to trap enough heat and air so we could breathe and not freeze to death. It could also easily block UV much the way transparent window glass can block UV. Without this sheet you'd need a spacesuit to survive, that suit would provide UV protection)

Other types of radiation would NOT be blocked by a simple sheet of plastic and these are more worrisome. The primary thing we leave behind when we leave earth will be the protection that come from the Earth's magnetic field. (To be fair to your original question, some degree of protection also comes from the mass of the atmosphere)

We use tools to protect against radiation all the time. When you get an x-ray at the dentist they put a big leaden apron over your center of mass. This is probably the easiest way to protect against radiation (put some mass between you and the radiation source so the radiation hits it instead of you). On the moon or Mars we'll probably build underground to protect against radiation and meteors (one additional thing the atmosphere protects against is falling space debris. The reason the moon is pockmarked and the earth is not is that falling debris burns up in our atmosphere. Any colonization in space will have to create protections against astroids with high relative velocity. This will probably consist of a suite of protections: mass, compartmentalization, puncture response plans and procedures)

[Cosmic rays](http://www.windows2universe.org/physical_science/physics/atom_particle/cosmic_rays.html) are also a concern. Extraordinarily high energy particles coming from space. Rock is probably the best way to protect against that as well.

Why not lead you might ask? Use what works. Lead works precisely because it's a handy way to put a lot of mass in a small space (it's heavy ;-) It currently costs four thousand dollars a pound to launch something into space so it'll cost $40,000 to launch a single lead apron into space. Economics will encourage us to use materials already existent at our destination as much as possible. Space mining could provide a source of heavy metals (imagine capturing a large astroid rich in heavy metals and using gold simply because it's very massive and suddenly quite plentiful), pretty as that is to imagine, we're decades from space mining so you'll probably see other solutions first.

We are also learning more about biological radiation protection as well. I could easily imagine gene therapy to grant humans additional radiation protections. Recent studies have begun to identify the mechanisms behind [the extraordinary natural radiation resistance of the Tardigrade](http://www.nature.com/news/tardigrade-protein-helps-human-dna-withstand-radiation-1.20648). Other [lessons and hints for biological resistance to the effects of radiation](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/07/130731093255.htm) come from the naked mole rat  I expect to see these treatments available within my lifetime. Especially if Elon [Musk's plans](https://www.wired.com/2016/09/elon-musk-colonize-mars/) humanity's expansion into space bear fruit. tl;dr first mission to mars in 2018, then large numbers of people every time the planets are at their closest orbits to each-other (every 27 months).

Any spacefaring species will need to create a whole suite of radiation protections. Some will be mechanical (mass shielding), some will be technological (electromagnetic shields), some we will incorporate into our biology (perhaps inspired by existing examples of biological radiation resistance). You ask is it possible. It's possible. And what's more, it's necessary in the near term. You'll probably live to see people going to space in large numbers and receiving radiation resistance treatments.

Whether we choose to modify our species permanently by making these traits inheritable is another question. If I may be allowed a prediction, I'd say that some will choose to do so and some won't. And those who do will thrive while those who don't will die. Perhaps evolution is still operating through human intelligence and choice. I expect evolution doesn't care how it operates. It just does.

Answer (score 1):

well without an atmosphere is different than without an magnetosphere. provided it changed slowly enough life including human might be able to handle the loss of the magnetosphere, lack of an atmosphere would no be something we could evolve to handle, eukaryotes are too reliant on oxygen.

Comment: Without magnetosphere atmosphere would be stripped by the solar wind

Comment: ([extremophile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremophile)) "microbial life has an amazing flexibility for surviving in extreme environments—niches that are extraordinarily hot, or acidic, for example—that would be completely inhospitable to complex organisms." IMO, it is extremely unlikely that humans will devolve into [Tardigrades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade).